# Override global Vite config assetsInlineLimit for individual file

Tags: base64, vite

#### Background

My project have a `vite.config.ts` that is not allow to change is set with `assetsInlineLimit: 0`.

I am trying to make an image to be in base64 so that it is still able to
show for no network scene (eg: Image for network error page).

I have tried `import image from "path/image.png?inline"`, but unfortunately, it does not work.

#### Current Workaround

The approach I am using now is using external library to convert the image to base64 and use it in the `<image>` tag.

#### Question

Is there a way for individual file to override the Vite global `assetsInlineLimit` config and leverage on `path/image.png?inline`?

Answer (score 0):

https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options#build-assetsinlinelimit accepts a function too, where you can override the behaviour based on filepath.

```
Type: number | ((filePath: string, content: Buffer) => boolean | undefined)
```

> If a callback is passed, a boolean can be returned to opt-in or opt-out. If nothing is returned the default logic applies.

Something like this maybe?

```js
assetsInlineLimit: (filePath) => {
  return filePath.includes("path/image.png?inline");
},
```